# How can instant impact can be detec with (9 axis)acc,gyro, magneto

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, instant

I have 9 axis sensor with acc, gyro,mag. Also ARM M0 processor without floating point unit. Delays can't not be tolerant in my project and aim is detection of (specific)instant motion(kind of reaction). Sometimes i got meanless values from the sensor even though there were no motion or any thing. So i got kind of median filter to ignore that kind of values. what's the best way to get instant motion?

Thank You